# Don't understand why UnboundLocalError occurs in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
print([[x,y,z] for x in range(0,x+1,1) for y in range(0,y+1,1) for z in range(0,z+1,1) if (x+y+z)!=n])
```

The above program shows "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment" error

Comment: Not sure why this was at -3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x`, `y` and `z` in the list comprehension are hiding the previously defined variables. You could use different names to avoid this hiding:

```
print([[a,b,c] for a in range(0,x+1,1) for b in range(0,y+1,1) for c in range(0,z+1,1) if (a+b+c)!=n])
```

Comment: I agree with this suggestion, but do you know why the error only comes on `y` and not on `x`?

Comment: Interesting. This works, though `[x for x in range(1, x+1)]`. So, I suppose it occurs the second time when the inner loop is executed with next value from outer loop.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am not 100% sure about this, but using `dis.dis` on the list comprehension, there seems to be a `LOAD_FAST` instruction on `y` inside of the `FOR_ITER` block `x`. That tries to look up the value of `y` inside of `co_varnames`, which hasn't been created yet.

Comment: @HampusLarsson interesting. But still I see the same calls for `x`. I might be missing something as I'm not used to analyzing `dis`, but in my eyes it seems like the same should happen earlier with `x`

Comment: @Tomerikoo The earlier call to `x` uses `STORE_FAST` which takes the value on the `TOS` (top of stack) and adds the value to `co_varnames`. So for `x` it first add the value, then for `y` it tries to retrieve the value, which hasn't been stored in `co_varnames` yet.

Comment: @HampusLarsson but the only `STORE_FAST` I see related to `x`, prior to its `LOAD_FAST` is the one from the `input` and the same goes for `y`. But I did notice now is that the `LOAD_FAST` of `y` is inside the list-comp code object and for some reason `x` is not. That explains it I guess assuming that under the list-comp closure `y` is not yet defined...

Comment: @Tomerikoo That is what I assume is happening as well. When inspecting the "correct" code, there are calls to `LOAD_DEREF` to `y`, which I think is because it realizes that `y` is not a locally created variable.